# MPMoviePlayerController black screen when app enter foreground from background

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm using an `MPMoviePlayerController` for playing video in my iPhone app.

When `MPMoviePlayerController` is playing, press home button on iPhone, make the app enter background.

Then tap the app's icon to make the app enter foreground, the `MPMoviePlayerController`'s view will be black screen for a short time, about 1 to 15 seconds.

How to make the `MPMoviePlayerController`'s video shows immediately when app came to foreground?

Special thx! :D

Comment: May be you can try to `pause` the `MPMoviePlayerController` when the app enters background and call `play` when it becomes active. I am not sure about this, that is why I am adding it as comment.

Answer (score -2):

NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://......"];

```
// Initialize a movie player object with the specified URL

self.moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;

[self.moviePlayer.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];

[self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];

[self.moviePlayer play];
```

I Hope this will help You.

Comment: This is in no way connected to the question.

Comment: Could you please tell us in what way this code runs fine with you ?